# Aws Lambda Deployment via CodePipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-codepipeline

I would like to deploy my Lambda methods by using Aws Codepipeline. However, when i follow Aws Codepipeline creation wizard, i couldn't understand which one should i choose at beta stage. Because, not only Aws Codedeploy, but also Elastic Beanstalk are concerning only EC2 instances. There is lack of tutorial about telling step by step to create pipeline for our lambda, apigateway deployments. How can i skip beta stage without choosing one of them?, or which one should i choose for my serverless architecture's deployments?.

Comment: Honestly if I was you I would look into the Serverless framework (https://github.com/serverless/serverless) along with using Jenkins or TeamCity. You might not need CodePipeline at all, but I think they have a way to integrate with an existing Jenkins server. Your build script on Jenkins or TeamCity would basically use the serverless cli to push the updated lambda functions.

Comment: you can invoke a lambda function, that exists only to build other lambda functions...

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct integrations for Lambda/API Gateway -> CodePipeline at the moment. You could certainly do something with Jenkins like @arjabbar suggested. Thanks for the feedback, we'll take this on our backlog.

Comment: This webinar shows how to publish a Lambda Function using CodePipeline.  However, it still does not answer OP. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKUdxhPMtVk

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation is available in CodePipeline now. This allows you to target cloudformation templates as Actions in the CodePipeline.

Here's an overview (the implementation was moved to a private repository after I changed positions):
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/continuous-deployment-for-serverless-applications/

In this pipeline we deploy a staging lambda, test its functionality, then deploy the production lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, the link in your answer is not opening. I came across https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/continuous-deployment-for-serverless-applications/ that covers this aspect as well.